# Conditional Expectation given joint distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Given 2 random variables $X,Y$, is it possible to write conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ in terms of their joint distributional function $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this could be done using Radon-Nikodym derivative

Answer (score 1):

Given $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$, you can obtain $P(x,y)$ and also $P(y)$ by integrate out $x$. This makes you know conditional probability $P(x|y)$, so does conditional expectation.

Comment: what is $P(x,y)$ here?

Comment: Please note $X,Y$ can be discrete, continuous or have both components.

Comment: Yes, this is always true no matter what kind of probability. Integrate on continuous part and sum on discrete part

Comment: Can you please define what is $P(x,y)$ and how how you will obtain it from $F_{X,Y}$

Comment: To interval where $F_{X,Y}$ is continuous, $P(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_{x,y}$ while discrete case replace derivative to minus